# How to connect declarations and If statements?

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin, textview, declaration

I want to change multiple textView colors through a couple if statements. All of them have different ID's except for the last part of them that ends with "....Price". I have tried just pasting the if statements on all of them but the build fails.

i have made declarations like this.

`textView1Price = ("+10.00")
 textView2Price = ("-10.00")
 textView3Price = ("0.00")`

and the if statements like so.

```
 if (colorID.text.startsWith("-")) {
        colorID.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    }
 if (colorID.text.startsWith("+")) {
        colorID.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    }
 if (colorID.text.startsWith("0.00")) {
        colorID.text = "_"
        colorID.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to connect the declarations to the If statements. I have tried something like this with partial success but can't list more that one declaration.

```
val colorID = textView1Price
```

i have also tried to find a way to reference the

```
text.contains("Price")
```

but have not been able to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Solution Follow up

```
//Declarations
//metal location A price
Price1 = ("+10.00")
//metal location B price
Price2 = ("-10.00")
//metal location C price
Price3 = ("0.00")
```

Android Studio suggested when statement over if

```
(1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        when {
            tv.text.startsWith("-") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            tv.text.startsWith("+") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
            tv.text.startsWith("0.00") -> {
                tv.text = "_"
                tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the TextViews that have ids like `textView?Price` you can use the `getIdentifier()` method to get their integer ids in a loop and then apply the conditions, like this (for 9 TextViews):

```
(1..9).forEach {
    val id = resources.getIdentifier("textView${it}Price", "id", packageName)
    val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
    if (tv.text.startsWith("-")) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    } else if (tv.text.startsWith("+")) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
    } else if (tv.text.startsWith("0.00")) {
        tv.text = "_"
        tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
    }
}
```

For `resources` and `packageName` you may need to supply a valid `Context` like:

```
val id = context.resources.getIdentifier("textView${it}Price", "id", context.packageName)
```

if your code is not inside an activity. 
For the other TextViews, if their ids have such a similarity, you can use the same method.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am fairly new to this. Could you elaborate a little more? For the (1..9).forEach what if i have no determined amount? The textView#Price example was for easy reference. The ID's of each only have Price as the commonfactor. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I assume that you have textviews like `textView1Price`, `textView2Price`,.. if the last one's id is textView1000Price, you just have to change the range to (`1..1000`). If the ids have not such a similarity then this code won't work.

Comment: i think i can make this work. ill just have to comment over all the entries so i can keep track of the values. example NewYorkPrice =. will be changed to textView1Price with a comment above stating New York. Thanks for your help i apprciate it.

Comment: As a sidenote, I tend to use `with(tv) { when { text.startsWith() -> ... } }` for Kotlin